# Just want to confirm that policeman & policemen (plural) were pronounced the same right?

Tags: pronunciation

I checked the dictionary & found that **Policeman** & **Policemen** both get their pronunciation as `/pəˈliːsmən/`.

That is weird because I thought  **Policemen** should be pronounced as `/pəˈliːsmen/`

And that applies for **postman** & **postmen** `/ˈpəʊst.mən/` & **fireman** & **firemen** `/ˈfaɪərmən/` as well

Answer (score 3):

It may depend on who is saying it. In my experience, the words are pronounced quite differently. Both with different sound and with different lengths.

Comment: It does depend on who is saying it.  There are regional differences that I didn't want to go into in detail.

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed pronounced the same [Edit: most of the time, see comments below].  Very often the vowel in a non-emphasized syllable is pronounced with a sort of "uh", called in phonetics a schwa and represented by the **ə** symbol.  You'll notice the same pronunciation of the **o** in the first syllable of *policeman* as well. If you wanted to make the distinction for some reason, you'd simply emphasize the syllable:

> I meant police*men*, not police*man*.

In some parts of the U.S. the word is pronounced with emphasis on the first syllable: PO-lice-man.  In this case, there's a secondary emphasis on the last syllable, and *man* and *men* are differentiated.

Comment: They are often pronounced the same, but not always. If I was talking to a child I might say, "No that's not mine, but why don't you take it over to that nice police***man*** over there. I'm sure he'll know what to do with it."

Comment: I think it also depends on how fast I am talking (the faster my utterance, the more likely the two words woud sound similar), and where the word appears in the sentence (for some reason, it seems like I might enunciate it more clearly at the end of a sentence than in the middle).

Comment: Yes, I agree.  There's also the regional differences in pronunciation.